# PyGame Y Axis Collision Detection

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Quite some time ago I created this very basic game using pygame. The aim of the game is to dodge the rectangles falling at you. First I wanted to add the ability to go up and down and not only strafe side to side. So I added the button presses, y changes, etc.. This all works great but there is one problem. If I go above an obstacle that is below me it still counts as a collision (or crash as I have named it in my code) even though I was no where near it. I believe that the problem is inside the `game_loop` function as that is where the collision logic happens.

Here is the code (No error codes appear):

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import base64
import io
import webbrowser

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
cyan = (0, 80, 200)
green = (0, 200, 0)
grey = (200, 200, 200)

pepe_width = 70

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Best Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

photo = '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'


output = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(photo))

pepeImg = pygame.image.load(output)


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (10, 10))


def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])


def pepe(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(pepeImg, (x, y))


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def crash():
    message_display('lel pal u ded')


def button(msg, x, y, w, h, a, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, (x, y, w, h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, (350, 450, 100, 50))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    TextRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), y + (h / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, TextRect)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
        LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("The Best Game", LargeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play", 350, 450, 100, 50, green, "play")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 3.5
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change
        gameDisplay.fill(grey)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        pepe(x, y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - pepe_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if y > display_height - pepe_width or y < 0:
            ctash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 0.1


        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + pepe_width > thing_startx and x + pepe_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                #webbrowser.open('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
                crash()



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

EDIT: This is the final working code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import base64
import io
import webbrowser

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
cyan = (0, 80, 200)
green = (0, 200, 0)
grey = (200, 200, 200)

pepe_width = 70
pepe_height = 70

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Best Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

photo = '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'


output = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(photo))

pepeImg = pygame.image.load(output)


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (10, 10))


def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])


def pepe(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(pepeImg, (x, y))


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def crash():
    message_display('lel pal u ded')


def button(msg, x, y, w, h, a, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, (x, y, w, h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, (350, 450, 100, 50))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    TextRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), y + (h / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, TextRect)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
        LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("The Best Game", LargeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play", 350, 450, 100, 50, green, "play")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 3.5
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change
        gameDisplay.fill(grey)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        pepe(x, y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - pepe_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if y > display_height - pepe_width or y < 0:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 0.1

        if (x < thing_startx + thing_width and x + pepe_width > thing_startx and
            y < thing_starty + thing_height and y + pepe_height > thing_starty):
            crash()
            webbrowser.open('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')




        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: you have a typo in the if statement:  "if y > display_height - pepe_width or y < 0: ctash()" I assume you meant crash(). It may not be the problem, but it likely won't help

Comment: I fixed the typo, still broken :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collision detection is broken. This should work:

```
if (x < thing_startx + thing_width and x + pepe_width > thing_startx and
    y < thing_starty + thing_height and y + pepe_height > thing_starty):
```

I highly recommend creating [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for your objects, because they have reliable and fast collision detection methods.

```
player = pygame.Rect(100, 200, 70, 70)
enemy = pygame.Rect(150, 200, 100, 100)
# In the main loop.
if player.colliderect(enemy):
    # do something.
```

Comment: I will try this out when I get home, and yes I probably should use .Rect, I've noticed the collision isnt too great even if it is set up properly.

Comment: Also do I also remove:  **if y < thing_starty + thing_height:** ?

Comment: Yes, replace your collision detection completely. By the way, `pygame.Rect.colliderect` does pretty much the same as the suggested solution, but it's implemented in C so it should be a lot faster.

Comment: I put it in my code and it works great! thanks. Also had to define pepe_height.